# Security risks of disabling CSRF protection for login via Facebook SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

We're trying to solve an issue some of our users experience with the Facebook login (using `facebook/php-graph-sdk`).

```
Cross-site request forgery validation failed. Required param "state" missing from persistent data.
```

We think we already have a good implementation of the SDK, and we're making sure that `session_create()` is called before `$fb->getRedirectLoginHelper()`. The issue might have to do with Safari's third-party cookies policy, and thus the session get lost somewhere between the login request and the callback request.

There're already many questions about this matter here in StackOverflow, but all seem to suggest overriding the `FBRLH_state` session variable with the value of the `state` param of the request.

```
$_SESSION['FBRLH_state'] = $_GET['state'];
```

However, that would disable the CSRF protection provided with the SDK. So, our question is what is the worse that could happen if we decided to disable CSRF protection for Facebook login? for both the redirect &JavaScript helpers.

Comment: If you have a cookie problem, then you should perhaps rather transport the session ID via GET or POST, instead of trying to “fix” the problem in other places, that are not the real cause of the issue ... A non-working session is likely to cause you other problems later on, too, no?

Comment: There used to be a workaround for such 3rd-party cookie issues in Safari, where you redirect the user to your domain first (so that is stops being “3rd party”), set a cookie there, and then redirect them back to whatever site embeds your app. Not sure if that still works, but maybe worth a try.